# Confusion related to convexity and non convexity of a problem

Tags: pca, optimization, sparse

I was reading this paper related to sparse PCA
[enter link description here](http://www.google.com.np/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sparse%20pca%20with%20constraints&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI12/paper/download/5109/5503&ei=HPTsUMffLaW30AGm_4HoCw&usg=AFQjCNEfeBg-qlb_k7-ATFQKt-cCb7eNfA&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.dmQ)

I didn't understand how they said that the function was convex or non convex

[image]

I wanted to know how in the screenshot attached above, the equation 3 is non convex. I am new to this so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you work through the simplest nontrivial case where $u$ is a 2-vector and $r=1$? The conditions in (3) limit $U$ to exactly two choices, which obviously form a non-convex set.

Comment: @whuber. Can you elaborate a bit more? I am sorry I am a bit new to this

Comment: Consider all 2 by 2 matrices $\mathbb{U}$ having only $r=1$ nonzero entry. Because the trace (the sum of the diagonal elements) needs to be nonzero, that entry must be on the diagonal, and because the trace needs to be $1$, that entry must be identical to $1$. This gives exactly two solutions $\pmatrix{1 0\\0 0}$ and $\pmatrix{0 0\\0 1}$. Both manifestly have rank $1$ and are positive semidefinite; *ergo*, the problem is to maximize $Tr(\mathbb{SU})$ over this two-element set of matrices. But this set obviously is not convex.

Comment: @whuber. The set just consists of two matrices. Further by definition of convex sets. $\theta_1U1+\theta2U2$ where U1 and U2 are the two matrices u've given doesn't belong to the set. It only consists of the two matrices u gave. That's why it is not convex set and eventually Tr(SU) is not convex set itself. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but take a little care with notation.  $Tr(\mathbb{SU})$ is a *number*, not a set. As it depends on $\mathbb{U}$ (considering $\mathbb{S}$ to be a fixed matrix), it is the *objective function* in this problem: the value to be maximized.

Comment: @whuber can u be available for chat. You have helped me a lot before as well. So I was wondering if we could chat so that I can be clear about few more things. I would really appreciate it